# How to convert string variable to integer in php?

Tags: php

I'm very new to php .I want to convert the string to integer value.

I used following code to convert

```
$val='(100*2)';
echo (int)($val); //This will showing output as 0
```

But `echo (int)((100*2)); /This will showing output as 200`

Please help me any one to solve this .Thanks advance

Comment: you will have to parse the string - where is it coming from?

Comment: Why are you even using it as a string?

Comment: I concatenate the values using some condition to generate formula .Finally the output comes like $string='((33*4)+( 3+5))'; I need to calculate the integer value from the above string .

Comment: just use simple  $value=100*2;  echo $value;  here you are useing '' and this is used for string  so no need to use '' for int var

Answer (score 3):

`(int)($val)` evaluates to 0 because `$val`'s value is not a numeric string (ie one that can be directly cast to a number).

If you really need this kind of functionality, try `eval()`:

```
$val='(100*2)';
echo (int)($val); //This will showing output as 0
eval('$newval='.$val.';');
echo $newval;
```

But be warned: `eval()` can be dangerous!

From http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php:

> Caution
>
> > The eval() language construct is very dangerous because it allows
> >     execution of arbitrary PHP code. Its use thus is discouraged. If you
> >     have carefully verified that there is no other option than to use this
> >     construct, pay special attention not to pass any user provided data
> >     into it without properly validating it beforehand.

**EDIT**: Added `.';'` to eval parameter to make it a legit php instruction.

Comment: Hi just i used this following code .What was requested from your end .                                                            $val='(100*2)'; 
echo (int)($val); //This will showing output as 0
eval('$newval='.$val);
echo $newval; //This will showing output as (100*2)             echo round($newval); //This will showing output as 0 ,             But i need the output as 200 instead of 0 .Can you help me

Comment: Hi, the 0 you are seeing comes from the first echo. `eval()` didn't work because I missed a semicolon at first (see my edit). Sorry! Now the output will be 0200 (0 from the first echo and 200 from the second)

Answer (score 1):

The most common suggestion will be - evaluate your string as PHP code, like:

```
$val = '(100*2)';
eval('$val = '.$val.';');
```

-but that's unsafe, `eval` should be avoided as long as possible.

Alternatively, there is [bcParser](http://bcparserphp.soft112.com/) for PHP, which can solve such issues. That's more safe than `eval`.

Finally, I doubt that you really need do such things - it seems you're solving some problem with wrong method (see [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) description)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using php eval function.
For that first you have to check for special characters and equation characters.

```
$val='(100*2)';
echo matheval($val);

function matheval($equation)
{
   $equation = preg_replace("/[^0-9+\-.*\/()%]/","",$equation);
   // fix percentage calcul when percentage value < 10
   $equation = preg_replace("/([+-])([0-9]{1})(%)/","*(1\$1.0\$2)",$equation);
   // calc percentage
   $equation = preg_replace("/([+-])([0-9]+)(%)/","*(1\$1.\$2)",$equation);
   // you could use str_replace on this next line
   // if you really, really want to fine-tune this equation
   $equation = preg_replace("/([0-9]+)(%)/",".\$1",$equation);
   if ( $equation == "" )
   {
        $return = 0;
   }
   else
   {
        eval("\$return=" . $equation . ";" );
   }
   return $return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I not recommended this, but you can use [eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) to suit your need

```
eval('$val = (100*2)');
echo intval($val);
```

Comment: eval is evil!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951373/when-is-eval-evil-in-php

Answer (score 0):

Why not just:

```
$x=intval(100);// <- or an other value from the cleaned user input
$y=intval(2);
$val=$x*$y;
echo $val;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not giving a goal.

I can just explain why your code works like it does.

'(100*2)' is a String that cannot be converted to int, since it does contain other chars than numbers. Every String that cannot be converted will result in 0.

echo (int)(100*2) will work, because you use numbers and no strings. No need to convert, either, would work without the cast, just echo (100*2);

Remember PHP use loose typing. You will almost never need to convert types. This scenario is very set up.

Comment: My ultimate aim of the code is used to one function to create a formula using certain rules and condition.Now this function return a formula string .here i want make it this string to integer actual value.Please help me